# Email drip campaign with CiviRules

Tags: email, civirules

We are interested in creating periodic emails for contacts in specific groups.

- If the contact is in group X, then every month, they should receive the next email in the flow.
- At the end of the set of emails, optionally, the flow should start over.

We typically use Chasse for our drip email campaigns, but Chasse only supports having a user in one journey at a time.  This doesn't work for us because our users are often in multiple email campaigns at once based on courses they enroll in.

We are currently considering building these flows in CiviRules.  I'm surprised to find there isn't an example of this in the documentation.

Does anyone have example CiviRules implementations for periodic e-mails / e-mail campaigns using CiviRules?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instructions:

- Install the Email API extension (it's available for in-app install)
- In CiviRules, you'll set the trigger to whatever you like (e.g. "Contact is added to group") with the appropriate condition (e.g. "Group is 'New Donors'").
- Create your mailing templates (**Mailing menu » Message Templates**).
- In your CiviRule, add a "Send an Email" action for each email in the campaign, setting the appropriate template for each.
- Finally, when editing the CiviRule, there will be an **Edit Delay** link next to each action.  Set these as appropriate for each email (e.g. one with no delay, one in 3 days, one in 10 days).

Comment: Thank you, Jon.  I didn't realize that delay was there.  So, question, will there only be one trigger that triggers multiple actions (emails) each with increasingly long delays?  I think I was conceptualizing it as I needed multiple time-based triggers but it sounds like I would only have one trigger (contact added) and if my email campaign was 10 emails long each spaced by 1 week then that one trigger would have 10 actions associated to the one trigger but each action would have increasing delays....do I have that right?

Comment: OK one more question: is there a way to say run this campaign essentially eternally in a loop?  For example, let's say we have 12 emails that should go out one every month.  When it's the new year, they should start over.  How would we do that in civirules?  At the end of the email series can you have an action to remove the person from the group, then re-add the person to the group, which would cause the whole civirule to fire again?  Thank you.

Comment: @richardsplayground Yes, I don't see why you couldn't do that.

Comment: And yes - one trigger/rule for the entire drip campaign.  You could do it with multiple rules, but there's no reason to do so.  It's also nice to have all the emails for a particular campaign packaged in a single rule if you have lots of these campaigns.

Comment: One more question, actually.  What happens if I remove the person from the group part-way through the series.  Is it possible to have CiviRules check if they are still in the group before sending each email?

Comment: Yes - when you set the delay there's a checkbox that lets you re-evaluate the original conditions before the action takes place.

Comment: This has been so, so, SO helpful to have such a concrete example and all these questions answered.  Thank you so much Jon.

Answer (score 0):

Reading your first 2 bullets, I was going to suggest Chasse.  I think it was a design decision of Chasse not to allow multiple concurrent journeys but if you have a compelling use-case and it does most of what you need then a PR (or fork) would be an option.

Comment: Yeah I've had conversations with the author about funding the additional work to make it handle multiple journeys at once but he was not willing to go there.  It looks like CiviRules can do what we need but if it couldn't my next move was going to be to see if I could fund some other developer to do this because I truly love Chasse - the UI is wonderful.  I just don't have the development chops to do it myself.